# Selecting negative Columns from lastrow of the specific columns

Tags: excel, vba, select, range, dynamic-columns

Dears i need your help as i need to select Reverse Columns from lastrow of the specific columns

For Example we have below data

[image]

so, i need to select column D to its last row including C,B,A columns but to the last row of the D

i tried below code it selects all these columns but to the last row of column A not column D

```
Dim RngD As Range
Set RngD = Range("D1", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

RngD.Offset(, -3).Resize(Rows.Count, 4).Select
```

[image]

Any Help!

Comment: `Set RngD = Range("A1", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` then `RngD.Select`

Comment: You can omit `RngD.Rows.Count`, it is default (understood): `RngD.Offset(, -3).Resize(, 4).Select`.